# Изменение порядка элемента массива с помощью лямбда-выражений

Tags: c#

Задачу на массив оформить с помощью лямда выражений. Элементы массива получить с помощью Random. Дан массив размера N. Поменять порядок его элементов на обратный.

Comment: Дан массив размера N. Поменять порядок его элементов на обратный.

Comment: изменить порядок на обратный с помощью лямбд? задание не очень понятно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

на данный момент решение я вижу так:

```
void Main()
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    var a = Enumerable.Range(1,10).Select(el=>rand.Next(1,10)).Reverse();
    //[6,6,2,2,9,3,4,1,5,7] примерно так
}
```

- `Enumerable.Range(1,10)` - создаёт набор десяти чисел начиная с единицы
- `Select(el=>rand.Next(1,10))` - создёт рандомные числа и выбирает их
- `Reverse()` - меняет их порядок на обратный